# Tflearn: how to build ResNet 152-layer model and extract the penultimate hidden layer's image feature?

Tags: image, tflearn, resnet

how to build 152-layer resnet and extract the penultimate hidden layer's image feature.

now I got a pre-trained ResNet 152-layer model http://download.tensorflow.org/models/resnet_v1_152_2016_08_28.tar.gz
I just want to use this 152-layer model to extract the image feature, now i want to extract the penultimate hidden layer's image feature
(just as show in the code).

1. The main question is how to build 152-layer ResNet model ? (i just see that set n = 18 then resnet
   is 110 layers.). Or how to build 50-layer ResNet model?
2. my extract the penultimate hidden layer's image feature code is right?

   ```
   from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import

   import tflearn
   from PIL import Image
   import numpy as np

   # Residual blocks
   # 32 layers: n=5, 56 layers: n=9, 110 layers: n=18
   n = 18

   # Data loading
   from tflearn.datasets import cifar10
   (X, Y), (testX, testY) = cifar10.load_data()
   Y = tflearn.data_utils.to_categorical(Y, 10)
   testY = tflearn.data_utils.to_categorical(testY, 10)

   # Real-time data preprocessing
   img_prep = tflearn.ImagePreprocessing()
   img_prep.add_featurewise_zero_center(per_channel=True)

   # Real-time data augmentation
   img_aug = tflearn.ImageAugmentation()
   img_aug.add_random_flip_leftright()
   img_aug.add_random_crop([32, 32], padding=4)

   # Building Residual Network
   net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 32, 32, 3],
                        data_preprocessing=img_prep,
                        data_augmentation=img_aug)
   net = tflearn.conv_2d(net, 16, 3, regularizer='L2', weight_decay=0.0001)
   net = tflearn.residual_block(net, n, 16)
   net = tflearn.residual_block(net, 1, 32, downsample=True)
   net = tflearn.residual_block(net, n-1, 32)
   net = tflearn.residual_block(net, 1, 64, downsample=True)
   net = tflearn.residual_block(net, n-1, 64)
   net = tflearn.residual_block(net, 1, 64, downsample=True)
   net = tflearn.residual_block(net, n-1, 64)

   net = tflearn.batch_normalization(net)
   net = tflearn.activation(net, 'relu')
   output_layer = tflearn.global_avg_pool(net)

   # Regression
   net = tflearn.fully_connected(output_layer, 10, activation='softmax')
   mom = tflearn.Momentum(0.1, lr_decay=0.1, decay_step=32000, staircase=True)
   net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer=mom,
                        loss='categorical_crossentropy')
   # Training
   model = tflearn.DNN(net, checkpoint_path='resnet_v1_152.ckpt',
                   max_checkpoints=10, tensorboard_verbose=0,
                   clip_gradients=0.)

   model.fit(X, Y, n_epoch=200, validation_set=(testX, testY),
         snapshot_epoch=False, snapshot_step=500,
         show_metric=True, batch_size=128, shuffle=True,
         run_id='resnet_cifar10')
   model.save('./resnet_v1_152.ckpt')


   #---------------
   # now extract the penultimate hidden layer's image feature
   img = Image.open(file_path)
   img = img.resize((32, 32), Image.ANTIALIAS)
   img = np.asarray(img, dtype="float32")
   imgs = np.asarray([img])
   model_test = tflearn.DNN(output_layer, session = model.session)
   model_test.load('resnet_v1_152.ckpt', weights_only = True)

   predict_y = model_test.predict(imgs)

   print('layer\'s feature'.format(predict_y))
   ```